# Are marriage mantras also mantras only?

Tags: mantras

How marriage mantras will work? Are they really mantras or just some meaningful sanskrit sentences? If those are just sentences then what is the significance of reading them in sanakrit? cant they be converted to some regional languages or simply ignore them as those are just sentences?

Some marriage mantras I am talking about are

**mangalyam thanthuna mena mamajeevana...**

**dharmecha ardhecha mokshecha...**

those are also mantras only? Then those mantras praises which god or goddess?